# No file and image can be uploaded in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, filesystems

I have a model like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='hi/')
```

And `Setting.py` like this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__)) + '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

But I can't upload any images or even create or save any `UserProfile` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `MEDIA_ROOT` set line to this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__)), 'media')
```